# Best way to convert Object[] to String[] or List<String>

Tags: c#, .net, string, types

I have a Data Row. I can get the items in it using the property `dataRow.ItemArray` which is of type `object[]`.
I need to convert this to `String[]` or `List<String>`

I see the methods `ToArray<>` and `ToList<>`. but dont know how to use it.Kindly help.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You have two options depending on the actual objects in dataRow.ItemArray

If there are actually string objects in the object[] you can just cast element wise.

```
dataRow.ItemArray.OfType<string>().ToList();
```

but if the objects are of another type, like int or something else you need to convert the to string (in this example with `.ToString()` but another custom method might be required in your case

```
dataRow.ItemArray.Select(o => o.ToString()).ToList();
```

**Edit:**
If you don't need `List<string>` or `string[]` explicitly you can leave the `.ToList()` out and get an `IEnumerable<string>` instead.

Comment: +1 For talking about *both* coercion and conversion. Consider mentioning/handling `null`/`DBNull` in conversion example as these are somewhat common cases (in my experience).

Answer (score 9):

```
 object[] a = new object[10];
 string[] b = Array.ConvertAll(a, p => (p ?? String.Empty).ToString())
```

(the line you want is the second)

Answer (score 4):

```
List<string> strList = objArray.Cast<String>();
```

You may want to check for nulls first:

```
List<string> strList = objArray.Select( o => o == null ? String.Empty : o.ToString() ).ToList();
```

Comment: Should point out that this does not cause conversion which may (or may not be) desired.

Comment: The second example is *not* just the first-with-a-null-check but an explicit *conversion*. This should be pointed out.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `System.Array.ConvertTo` with `System.Convert.ToString` as the delegate.

Answer (score 3):

ToArray and ToList won't quite do what you want, as they will only return an object array or list. You need to massage the data into strings first, and `Select` can help. Try this:

```
 dataRow.ItemArray.Select(i => i == null ? string.Empty : i.ToString()).ToArray();
```

Comment: I prefer `"" + i` in this case as it has the same effect as the ternary w.r.t. nulls -- but style-subjective :)